# can't save record

Tags: cakephp

I can't understand it doesn't update or save any records I put. Can you tell me what's wrong?

This is my StockController function `add`

```
function add()
{
    if (!empty($this->data['Stocks']))
    {
        if ($this->Stocks->Save($this->data['Stocks']))
        {
            ($this->flash('Your Inventory has been added! /Stocks/'));
        }
    }
}
```

this the add.ctp

```
 <h1>Add Inventory</h1>    
<form action="<?php echo $this->Html->url("/Stocks/add"); ?>" method="post">    

    <p>    
        ProductName:      
        <?php echo $this->Form->varchar('Stocks/ProductName', array('size' => '40'))?>    
    </p>    
    <p>    
        Price:      
        <?php echo $this->Form->integers('Stocks/Price', array('size' => '10'))?>    
    </p>    
<p>
   Quantity:
   <?php echo $this->Form->integers('Stocks/Quantity', array('size' => '5'))?>
</p>
    <p>    
        <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Save') ?>    
    </p>  

</form>
```

Comment: This isn't 4chan. We're professionals around here; the `y u no` meme and `XD` emoticon don't add to the value of your question, so please refrain from using them.

Comment: li aung yip - sorry , i edit it .

Comment: Also; You haven't given nearly enough context for us to begin troubleshooting. Code examples should be [short, *self-contained*, compilable examples](http://sscce.org) where posssible.

Comment: thats all now can you see the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't mention which version of CakePHP you are using and there's quite a bit of none-standard code in your example.

Models should be singular:

```
function add()
{
    if (!empty($this->data))
    {
        if ($this->Stock->Save($this->data))
        {
            ($this->flash('Your Inventory has been added! /Stocks/'));
        }
        else {
            debug($this->Stock->validationErrors);
        }
    }
}
```

(the else I've added will show any validation errors)

Your form field names aren't formatted correctly:

```
h1>Add Inventory</h1>    
  <?php echo $this->Form->create('Stock'); ?>

    <p>    
        ProductName:      
        <?php echo $this->Form->varchar('Stocks.product_name', array('size' => '40'))?>    
    </p>    
    <p>    
        Price:      
        <?php echo $this->Form->integers('Stock.price', array('size' => '10'))?>    
    </p>    
<p>
   Quantity:
   <?php echo $this->Form->integers('Stock.quantity', array('size' => '5'))?>
</p>
    <p>    
        <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Save') ?>    
    </p>  

<?php echo $this->Form->end('Submit'); ?>
```